# JQuery event tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery

in some function I remove element like this `$('#'+id+' img.load').remove();` , how can i track this event and run custom code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(function($){
  var remove_orig = $.fn.remove;

  $.fn.remove = function(){
    console.log('Remove called');
    remove_orig.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

You can "hook" in to any jQuery function and place your own handling code within (including logging method(s)) which will execute *before* the native jQuery code is executed.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bVYWS/) (another version with the [selector shown](http://jsfiddle.net/bVYWS/1/))

---

Catching the removal is easy using the above overload. Simply alter the hook to fire a trigger before (or after) jQuery gets to it:

```
(function($){
  var remove_orig = $.fn.remove;

  $.fn.remove = function(){
    this.trigger('removing');
    remove_orig.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})(jQuery);

$('#foo').bind('removing',function(e){
    alert('#foo is being removed');
});

$('#foo').remove();
```

Comment: but how can i check what element was removed? Coz if I understand rightly,  this code runs on every remove of any element

Comment: @Yekver iterate over them inside the new function - `$(this).each(...)`

Comment: @Yekver: See the second demo, it shows how you can retrieve which element(s) were removed by access the selector being used.

Comment: @Yekver: Here's a different version of the above creating a `removed` event you can bind to: http://jsfiddle.net/bVYWS/2/

Answer (score 3):

One way is to "trigger" a custom event (in this example I am using window):

```
$('#'+id+' img.load').remove();
$(window).trigger("MyElementRemoved", [id]);
```

Then in another part of your code "handle" the event:

```
$(window).bind("MyElementRemoved", function(e, elementId) {
   alert("element removed: " + elementId);
}
```